# Element not showing when left 100% used

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a navigation bar which shows sub menu next to the navigation baron when hovered over similar to screenshot below.

[image]

However, when I try to use `left: 100%` the sub menu completely disappears. I did some testing and it looks like whenever the sub menu overflows the main navigation bar it just cuts the element.

This is how it looks like with `left: 50%`. As you can see the element is there.

[image]

This is how it looks like when `left: 80%`. As you can see the element gets cut and does not overflow the main navigation bar.

[image]

This is how it looks like with `left: 100%`. The element does not show at all.

[image]

Here is a codepen for the navigation bar. https://codepen.io/aheldes/pen/OJmGYYW

And here is the CSS for the side menu.

```
.navbar2.closed .navLinks li .subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove "overflow: auto" from your "navLinks" or change it to "visible", the subMenu becomes visible. "overflow: auto" means you want to have a scrollbar in case some content overflow is detected.

However, your submenu is positioned absolutely and thus taken out of the normal page flow, which means there is no overflow in your "navLinks".

Comment: Sorry Im not the best with CSS. As you mentioned, my submenu is out of the normal page flow so there is no overflow. Then why does the overflow affect this? Or is there a way to fix this while keeping the overflow on y axis? Thanks!

Comment: overFLOW means that something FLOWS beyond the borders of your div. "overflow: auto" means "wait until you detect an overFLOW, then show a scrollbar". Your submenu is placed outside its container, but no overflow can be detected because there is no flow at all due to the absolute positioning. You can fix this by avoiding "overflow: auto"

Comment: Ok, I understand that but why does in not work if I use `overflow-x: visible` and `overflow-y: auto` ? On y axis the sub menu wont ever overflow and when it overflows on x axis it will just show. I need the y axis overflow to be auto as I need the scrolling option on y axis.

Comment: To clarify this again: The default setting is "overflow: visible". Everything outside your div will be visible, even though it is outside the div. "overflow: hidden" or "overflow: auto" means "don't show content outside the div". That's why your submenu is invisible.

Comment: Ok got it now! I think I also found the solution. The navbar wont ever overflow while it is closed. So I can just use `overflow: visible` when its closed and then use `overflow: auto` when it is not closed. Thank you very much @Floyd !

Comment: Didi you set the opacity of your submenu to 1 when you tried overflow-x?